# Ubuntu - Access Windows Partition

Tags: ubuntu

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but...

I had a problem with my Ubuntu install, and I need to uninstall it. However, I have one folder on there with an important assignment in it that I'd like to keep still.
I can still get in to Ubuntu with the command line, and it was installed beside Windows so I had access to my Windows partition as well. My question is - is it possible to access the Windows partition using the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can be accessed from the "command line", or terminal as it is often termed in Linux operating systems. Just cd to the mountpoint of your Windows partition, then cp the file into the directory. Or; if you want a GUI (Graphical User Interface), you can boot off of the Ubuntu install disk and mount the Ubuntu partition from there (or your Wubi file if you installed via Wubi).